# executeQueryLocally does not work well when using withParameters

Tags: caching, breeze

I'm trying to use executeQueryLocally in a query that has 'withParamters', but it seems that I get locally cached data even when using new values in the 'withParameters'.  It is as if 'executeQueryLocally' ignores values in 'withParameters'.

here is the code in the client side:

```
var query = EntityQuery.from('ProductsFilteredByCategory')
            .withParameters({ categoryId: categoryId })
            .select("productId,name,desc,shopPrice,webPrice")
            .orderBy('name');

var p = manager.executeQueryLocally(query);
if (p.length > 5) {
    productsObservable(p);
    return Q.resolve();
}
```

here is the code for 'ProductsFilteredByCategory' on the server side:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IQueryable<Product> ProductsFilteredByCategory(int categoryId)
    {
        Category category = _contextProvider.Context.Categories.Include("Products").Include("SubCategories").First(c => c.CategoryId == categoryId);
        var prods = from p in category.Products select p;
        category.SubCategories.ForEach(sc => prods = prods.Concat(_contextProvider.Context.Categories.Include("Products").First(c => c.CategoryId == sc.CategoryId).Products));
        return prods.AsQueryable();
     }
```

what happens is that after I retrieve the data once with 'p.length > 5' being true, in every subsequent call 'p.length > 5' is still true even when 'categoryId' is different, so the data that is bound to the observable is loaded once and never changes.

Thanks for your help !

Elior

Answer (score 1):

The *EntityQuery.withParameters* method is **NOT** intended for local query use. (We should probably document this better).

*WithParameters* sends application domain specific parameters that can only be interpreted on the server.  Unlike with 'where', 'orderBy', 'take' etc, there is no global interpretation that can be determined for a *withParameters* call. It can only be understood within the context of the server side method that accepts the parameters.